# SQL - Conversão de número inteiro e número decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um campo `qtfornecedor` do tipo *numeric(10, 3)*. Quando o valor armazenado dele é *10*, ele me retorna na consulta como *'10.000'*.

Tentei manipular o valor com um `IIF`, funciona para quando o valor armazenado é inteiro, exemplo *10*. Porém para casos de quando o valor armazenado é decimal, como *'10.000'*, ele me retorna inteiro *10*.

```
SELECT 
    cdempresa                               
    ,nmempresa
    ,cdproduto
    ,nmproduto      
    ,IIF(RIGHT(qtfornecedor,3) = 0, FORMAT(qtfornecedor, '#'), FORMAT(qtfornecedor, '##########.###')) as qtfornecedor                            
    ,unidade
    ,vlfornecedor                                     
FROM 
    [dbo].[negociacao]
WHERE 
    nrochamado  = 11104
```

Comment: *"Quando o valor armazenado dele é 10, ele me retorna na consulta como '10.000'."* bem se isso está errado, a seguir vc afirma *"Porém para casos de quando o valor armazenado é decimal, como '10.000', ele me retorna inteiro 10."* sinceramente não entendi, afinal o que quer que retorne???

Answer (score 0):

Tente aplicar fazer um [`CAST()`](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-decimal-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20CAST()%20function%20to%20convert%20an%20integer%20to,a%20decimal%20value%20(12.00).) na consulta, especificando que quer três casas decimais:

```
SELECT 
    cdempresa                               
    ,nmempresa
    ,cdproduto
    ,nmproduto      
    ,CAST(qtfornecedor AS DECIMAL(10,3)) as qtfornecedor                            
    ,unidade
    ,vlfornecedor                                     
FROM 
    [dbo].[negociacao]
WHERE 
    nrochamado  = 11104
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi corretamente a questão, mas experimente alterar a condição utilizada no IIF conforme segue abaixo:

```
,IIF(qtfornecedor = floor(qtfornecedor),
```

Nessa sugestão está sendo verificado se o valor da coluna é igual ao valor inteiro da coluna que é retornado pela função Floor.

Espero que ajude